# Avoid autonotification display from GCM using notificacion push in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

As we know, developing on Android we can handle push notification and show a custom view depending on our logic. But there is a problem, if I send a push notification with a content and title from the server android will auto-display the notification and if I handle them at the same time the phone shows both, mine and the auto-displayed.

How can I disable auto display of the notification in these cases.

Why do I need to do this?
I am using OneSignal to send push notifications for both android and ios. The second one need to receive a content and title to be shown but this is not mandatory for android and I want to be able to show a custom view in this case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the displaying of the OneSignal notification by the SDK by setting up a `NotificationExtenderService` per the OneSignal [Background Data and Notification Overriding](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-customizations#background-data-and-notification-overriding) documentation. Use the `NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample` class example shown in step 2 and return `true` instead of `false` to let the SDK know your handling the notification.

Comment: Thanks sir. It is perfect.